# How to copy from character array to character pointer?

Tags: c

I am trying to copy from a character array to character pointer.
My code:

```
char str[] = "Hello World";
char *result = (char *)malloc(strlen(str)+1);
int index=0;
while(index <= strlen(str))
{
  *result = str[index];
  result++;
  index++;
}
```

This above code is not working and below code is working

```
char str[] = "Hello World";
char *result = (char *)malloc(strlen(str)+1);
int index=0;
while(index <= strlen(str))
{
  result[index] = str[index];
  index++;
}
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: The first code *is* working, well almost anyway. The problem with it is that you *modify* the pointer so after the loop it will not point to the original location. If you make another pointer variable and before the loop make it too point to `result` then you will see that it will work.

Comment: How do you know the first code _is not working_?

Comment: You should use `index <= strlen(str)` – 'less or equal' rather than 'less than'.

Comment: Note that it's inefficient to call `strlen` repeatedly. It doesn't change, after all.

Comment: As pointed out by CiaPan, you forgot to copy the trailing `\0`; your resulting string is an unterminated string. This might lead to undefined behavior in subsequent code.

Comment: @CiaPan: `<=` is correct here, but you should explain why. (You need the copy the last `\0` as well)

Comment: To answer the question in the title, use `strcpy(result,str)`

Comment: @Joachim can you pls explain your point little more..

Comment: @CiaPan its not working coz I have checked it.

Comment: **How** did you check it?

Comment: @CiaPan after while loop I am trying to print result

Comment: **What** result do you print? The one pointed at by `result`...? But the `result` variable is no longer the same as it was before the loop! You have incremented it multiple times inside the loop, so now it points **past the copied string**...

Comment: Thanks CiaPan now I got your point. Taking another pointer to carry starting address is working.

Comment: That's the point: if you make some mistake in the program design, most probably you'll make the same mistake in testing for errors. We usually can't see our own mistakes, that's why the author is the worst choice for a testing person. Always take someone else to validate your idea, algorithm, implementation or product. At least a rubber duck – see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your first snippet you modify the pointer in the loop, so after the loop it will no longer point to the same location returned by the `malloc` call.

Look at it this way, after the call to `malloc` the pointer and the memory look like this:

```
result
|
v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

After the first iteration of the loop it will look like this:

```
    result
    |
    v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| H |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

And after the loop is done it will look like this

```
                                                 result
                                                 |
                                                 v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
| H | e | l | l | o |   | W | o | r | l | d | \0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
```

The copying is made, but the pointer no longer points to the original position.

[Note: Before the copying, the memory allocated by `malloc` will not be "empty" or initialized in any way, I just show it like that here for simplicity's sake.]

Comment: maybe we should add that using the `result` pointer this way OP won't even be able to `free` it anymore; that's why most of the cases I prefer array notation, it's also more readable

Answer (score 9):

we simply use the strcpy function to copy the array into the pointer.

```
     char str[] = "Hello World";
     char *result = (char *)malloc(strlen(str)+1);
     strcpy(result,str);
```

Comment: I want to implement strcpy() in my own way.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code.. 
Use strcpy() function.

```
char str[] = "Hello World";
char *result = (char *)malloc(strlen(str)+1);
strcpy(result,str);
```

Answer (score 2):

Already you allocate a memory for that pointer, so you can simply use the strcpy() function to copy the characters

```
 strcpy(result,str);
```

str copied to result.

Comment: its better to use strncpy instead of strcpy i guess

Comment: @sudhi - If we want to copy specified length of characters then we can use `strncpy()`. Here the whole array copied to the pointer, so we can simply use the `strcpy()` function.

Comment: @Bhuvanesh-You are correct , both strcpy and strncpy solves this purpose . But strncpy will provide more control, i mean to say sometime strcpy causes stack corruption (this can happen if we try to copy more than intended data from source to destination).

Comment: @sudhir That's not true in this case because the output buffer was allocated with `malloc(strlen(str)+1)` Therefore, `strcpy` is guaranteed to work correctly and not overflow the buffer.  If a fixed size output buffer was being used, and the length of the input string was unknown, then `strncpy` would be a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there is no practical reason to modify your pointers (like you do in the first snippet) when you can just add an offset (like you do in the second snippet). It just makes the code a little bit harder to get right.

For the first snippet, try saving the original `result` like this:

```
char *result = ...
char *start = result;
```

And after the loop, try printing `start`, instead of `result`. It should point to the newly copied string, like you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Your first code snippet copied the string perfectly , but in this process you moved allocated character pointer. If it has to work save its initial value in some temporary pointer

```
char str[] = "Hello World";
char *result = (char *)malloc(strlen(str)+1);
char *tmp = result;
int index=0;
while(index <= strlen(str))
{
  *result = str[index];
  result++;
  index++;
}
printf("%s\n", tmp);
```